# vs code and docker picking up folder bind mount incorrectly

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I tried running my container like so

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v ${PWD}/src:/var/www/src php-env
```

but under dev containers, I'm seeing `src` mapped to `/var/www/src/src`

The container runs fine and this mapping issue only seems to impact vs code. Any help on this would be much appreciated.